# add line to a file ONLY if it is not in file already

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to add the following line:

```
nohup java -jar /mnt/fusion/nfs/labStats/LabInfoAutoLog.jar > /dev/null &
```

to the end of the file `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` if it does not already exist.

How can I do that from *linux* command line? I assume `grep` or `sed` would work, but I am not familiar enough with either to get it to work. Right now I use `echo`, but that just keeps adding it over and over again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you want it at the end of the file:

```
LINE="nohup java -jar /mnt/fusion/nfs/labStats/LabInfoAutoLog.jar > /dev/null &"
FILE=/etc/rc.d/rc.local
grep -q "$LINE" "$FILE" || echo "$LINE" >> "$FILE"
```

Answer (score 2):

one option is two steps:

```
grep -q "yourline" /path/file||sed -i '/..place../ a \the line' file
```

also possible to do with awk,

save all lines in array, during saving if the line was found, exit. otherwise, add the line in `END{}` block to the right place.

P.S. **You didn't tell in the file, where to add that line.**

Comment: +1 for a cleaner solution than mine. I think he just wants to append it.

Comment: He says that currently uses `echo` so it will be the last one (dollar sign in `sed`).

Comment: @Birei when I answered it, there was no the `echo` part. :( but if he used echo, you are right. it should go to the last line.